# Jenkins Plugin Dev repeatableProperty Error

Tags: plugins, jenkins, jelly

I want to achieve some nested properties in the config of my build and i need to use repeatableProperty for that.

Everytime i add repeatableProperty to my jelly File i get an Exception when loading the config page.

```
<f:entry>
   <f:repeatableProperty field="test"></f:repeatableProperty>
</f:entry>
```

Then this error appears:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.apache.commons.jelly.JellyTagException: jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/apache-maven-3.3.3/testplugin/target/work/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/jenkins-core-1.621.jar!/lib/form/repeatableProperty.jelly:66:69: <st:include> Error setting property 'class', exception - org.apache.commons.beanutils.ConversionException: No value specified for 'Class'
```

I had a look at some other Plugins and they all just use the repeatableProperty like this. Additionally i googled a lot but there are not many matches, and the matches which i found doesnt help. Need your help guys.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I just bumped into it today and no luck finding a solution, even when looking at https://github.com/jenkinsci/scp-plugin/commit/e477fe4e903d54605dc83fcf3f3e2a75b4a653e9 and seeing what is different.

Comment: Unfortunately no - completely did another stuff then :(

Comment: Ok - I got it working but I can't confirm exactly how - I ensured repeatable was used in the original jelly then moved the block of repeated config to it's own config as it shows in the github link.

I then did a clean build. Just stopping and restarting the jenkins server didn't seem to work to much annoyance. 

I think this finally fixed it as I was able to generate pipeline syntax that looks good.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the field 'test' was not accessible (missing getter).

Some further info (regarding descriptors) might be found in the [repeatableProperty source](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/core/src/main/resources/lib/form/repeatableProperty.jelly).

Answer (score 0):

I also came across this and the problem was that Jenkins couldn't find the descriptor for the class. The descriptor was defined but couldn't be loaded due to an incorrectly declared dependency.